# Failed to save few order in SQL Server database when multiple user post order through ASP.NET API 2 at the same time

Tags: c#, sql-server, concurrency, asp.net-web-api2, system-design

I have a web application which runs in IIS 7 and using SQL Server 2014 & web API2 in SOLID principle.

I have a Order Table which contains 51 column, where I save orders details from multiple client.

Firstly i validate the order details(duplicate,order id existence etc) and then I save it to the same table.

My MVC controller are decorated with Asynchronous type.

I am using transaction & logging in stored procedure where I wrote Insert query.

I googled the same issue,but a bit confused who to implement a quick solution for this.

My questions are:

1. What should be the right System design to handle such concurrent order request.
2. How should I design my database tables or stored procedure so that order can be saved successfully.
3. How should I optimize or introduce any new coding technique to solve such concurrent traffic at least 500 orders per sec.

I would be very glad if somebody can help me out with an example.

```xml
Error occurred on 10/5/2020 10:43:12.968, at bookingController/CacheOrderDetails Action
System.InvalidOperationException: BeginExecuteReader requires an open and available
Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__174_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryAsync>d__23`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at DAL.DbHelper.<StoredProcWithParamsAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext() in D:\SamWorkspace\DMS_Live_28\DAL\DbHelper.cs:line 303
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Repository.Impl.ApiIntegration.<CacheOrderDetails>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\SamWorkspace\DMS_Live_28\Repository\Impl\ApiIntegration.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at bookingController.<CacheOrderDetails>d__59.MoveNext() in c:\DMS\LIVE_CODE\DmsLive_PublishCode\App_Code\api\bookingController.cs:line 1357
```

ActionMethod

```
 public async Task<string> CacheOrderDetails(modelManifest Obj, Int64 UserId, Int64 CustId)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("");
        #region declare payload for Save Manifest
        var data = new
        {
            CreatedById = UserId,
            CustId = CustId,
            AwbNo = Obj.AWB_NUMBER,
            OrderNo = Obj.ORDER_NUMBER,
            ProductType = Obj.PRODUCT,
            Consignee = Obj.CONSIGNEE,
            ConsigneeAdd1 = Obj.CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS1,
            ConsigneeAdd2 = Obj.CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS2,
            ConsigneeAdd3 = Obj.CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS3,
            DestCity = Obj.DESTINATION_CITY,
            DestPin = Obj.PINCODE,
            State = Obj.STATE,
            Mobile = Obj.MOBILE,
            Telephone = Obj.TELEPHONE,
            ItemDesc = Obj.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
            Pieces = Obj.PIECES,
            Colvalue = Obj.COLLECTABLE_VALUE,
            DeclValue = Obj.DECLARED_VALUE,
            ActualWeight = Obj.ACTUAL_WEIGHT,
            VolmWeight = Obj.VOLUMETRIC_WEIGHT,
            Length = Obj.LENGTH,
            Breadth = Obj.BREADTH,
            height = Obj.HEIGHT,
            PickupName = Obj.PICKUP_NAME,
            PickupAdd1 = Obj.PICKUP_ADDRESS_LINE1,
            PickupAdd2 = Obj.PICKUP_ADDRESS_LINE2,
            PickupPin = Obj.PICKUP_PINCODE,
            PickupPhone = Obj.PICKUP_PHONE,
            PickupMobile = Obj.PICKUP_MOBILE,
            ReturnPin = Obj.RETURN_PINCODE,
            ReturnName = Obj.RETURN_NAME,
            ReturnAdd1 = Obj.RETURN_ADDRESS_LINE1,
            ReturnAdd2 = Obj.RETURN_ADDRESS_LINE2,
            ReturnPhone = Obj.RETURN_PHONE,
            ReturnMobile = Obj.RETURN_MOBILE,
            VendorCode = Obj.VENDOR_CODE,
        };
        #endregion
        if (data != null)
        {
            //  Int32? ShipmentId = client.CreateShipment_ApiOnly(data);
            Int32? ShipmentId = await client.CacheOrderDetails(data);
            if (ShipmentId > 0 & Obj.PRODUCT.Contains("REV"))
            {
                #region declare payload for Save Manifest (QC params)
                var QcParam = new
                {
                    // ShipmentId = ShipmentId,
                    TempId = ShipmentId,
                    DrsUid = 0,
                    QC1_Text = Obj.QC1_Text,
                    QC2_Text = Obj.QC2_Text,
                    QC3_Text = Obj.QC3_Text,
                    QC4_Text = Obj.QC4_Text,
                    QC5_Text = Obj.QC5_Text,
                    QC6_Text = Obj.QC6_Text,
                    QC7_Text = Obj.QC7_Text,
                    QC8_Text = Obj.QC8_Text,
                    QC9_Text = Obj.QC9_Text,
                    QC10_Text = Obj.QC10_Text,

                    QC1_Val = Obj.QC1_Val,
                    QC2_Val = Obj.QC2_Val,
                    QC3_Val = Obj.QC3_Val,
                    QC4_Val = Obj.QC4_Val,
                    QC5_Val = Obj.QC5_Val,
                    QC6_Val = Obj.QC6_Val,
                    QC7_Val = Obj.QC7_Val,
                    QC8_Val = Obj.QC8_Val,
                    QC9_Val = Obj.QC9_Val,
                    QC10_Val = Obj.QC10_Val
                };
                #endregion

                int? QcResult = DbCust.SaveShipmentQC_Details(QcParam);
                if (QcResult == 0 || QcResult == null)
                {
                    message.Append("Unable to update QC records");
                }
                else
                    message.Append("SUCCESS");
            }
            else
            {
                if (ShipmentId != null && ShipmentId > 0 && !Obj.PRODUCT.Contains("REV"))
                {
                    message.Append("SUCCESS");
                }
                else
                    message.Append("Record already exists");
            }
            return message.ToString();
        }
        else
            return "FAILURE";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError("bookingController/CacheOrderDetails Action", ex);
        return "FAILURE";
    }
}
```

Implementation Class

```
  public async Task<Int32> CacheOrderDetails(object o)
    {
       // return DbHelper.StoredProcWithParamsAsync<Int32>("SaveOrderDetails", o).FirstOrDefault();
        var res = await DbHelper.StoredProcWithParamsAsync<Int32>("SaveOrderDetails", o);
        return res.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

DB Helper Class

```
  public static async Task<List<T>> StoredProcWithParamsAsync<T>(string procname, dynamic parms, string connectionName = null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = GetOpenConnectionAsync(connectionName))
        {
            var res= await connection.QueryAsync<T>(procname, (object)parms, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return res.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Connection String Declaration

```
 public static SqlConnection GetOpenConnectionAsync(string name = null)
    {

        string connString = "";
        connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr1"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
        connection.OpenAsync();
        return connection;
    }
```

Comment: Are you being any errors for the orders which are not saved in the database? Can you share the code which saves the data to the database?

Comment: I edited my question and added the error log- Please have a look.

Comment: Can you also share the code which throws the exception?

Comment: Ok , I am sharing my function as well.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Ranpariya I have updated the Source code in my question.

Comment: @TomTom - Could you please help me out, I have updated the code.